# mySQL - adding predefined values after/during insert? Is there a better approach?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables

- tbl_products - from here I will select randomly products
- tbl_verify - I need to insert here 12 random products from tbl_products and assign it to the 4 different users. 3 products to each user.

1st part to get the random products and insert into other table is of course easy. But I didn't know how to assign those products to the different users (4 users & each need to have 3 products). So my approach was to go with temp table with the following procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_verify; 

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_verify()
BEGIN

-- trunc the temp table   
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_tbl;

-- reset auto_increment
ALTER TABLE temp_tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

-- insert random producst into temp table
insert into temp_tbl (`prod_id` ,`closed_on` ,`closed_by`)
SELECT prod_num as prod_id, DATE_FORMAT (closed,'%d.%m.%Y' )as closed_on ,agent  as closed_by
FROM tbl_products a
WHERE DATE(closed) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 12; 

-- update temp table and assign products to the users
update temp_tbl
set verify_by =
case
when id in (1,2,3) then 1
when id in (4,5,6) then 2
when id in (7,8,9) then 3
when id in (10,11,12) then 4
else 0
end
;

-- insert data from temp table to final table 
insert into tbl_verify (`prod_id` ,`closed_on` ,`closed_by` ,  verify_by)
select prod_id, closed_on, closed_by, verify_by
from temp_tbl
;

commit;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

To explain what I do:

- trunc & reset auto_increment of temp table
- Randomly select 12 products
- Insert randomly selected products into a temp table
- products will have ID 1-12 in the temp table
- update temp table by adding user ID to each product ID (when product 1 then user 1, etc)
- insert data in the final table by selecting it from a temp table

Everything is working fine, just wanted to check is there a better approach to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ALTER TABLE temp_tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` is superfluous, the `TRUNCATE` already does that for you.

Your temporary table (and your whole procedure) is superfluous, too. You can do this all in one statement with the help of [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

```
insert into tbl_verify (`prod_id`, `closed_on`, `closed_by`, verify_by)
select prod_id, closed_on, closed_by, user from (
SELECT prod_num as prod_id, DATE_FORMAT(closed,'%d.%m.%Y') as closed_on ,agent  as closed_by
, @row := @row + 1 as row 
, case when @row between 1 and 3 then 1
       when @row between 4 and 6 then 2
       when @row between 7 and 9 then 3
       when @row between 10 and 12 then 4
       else 0 end as user
FROM tbl_products a
, (select @row := 0) v
WHERE DATE(closed) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 12
) sq
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great!
Knew there must be better way than mine.